# Making multiple individual keys in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I have below view

```
{
  "_id": "_design/view2",
  "_rev": "7-12d726e051cc03a083b0b0fcffd721fd",
  "views": {
    "view2": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  emit([doc._id,doc.pos, doc.id16, doc.Oid, doc.resultTime],1);\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

I want to query bt single key value. For example, I want all the documents with Oid=123 and I don't worry about other key values. How can I do that?

Also, what other way is available to get the documents by querying with any single value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to either create a view for each key you want to query by (as you seem to be attempting), or usually easier: Use the `_find` endpoint with Mango queries. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another view in the design document that emits only `oid` field and use that view in your query. It can be done by changing `views` in your design document to following:

```js
"views": {
    "view2": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  emit([doc._id,doc.pos, doc.id16, doc.Oid, doc.resultTime],1);\n}"
    },
"byOrderId": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  emit(doc.Oid, 1);\n}"
    }
  }
```

P.S. In the above view(`byOrderId`) I have emitted Oid as the key and `1` as value. You can change the emitted value in case you need any other field of the document, or you can use `include_docs` parameter of the query if your use case needs the whole document.

Comment: Not a good idea to `emit` the document id as it's always present in view results.